# OOM after n iterations in tensorflow without further tensor allocation

Tags: optimization, tensorflow

Several times, when working using as much GPU memory as possible, I've experienced OOM errors only after a certain number of training iterations have passed (without allocating new tensors explicitly). Reducing just a bit the batch size (i.e from 32 to 30) has always solved the problem, but I can't understand what should be causing this behabior.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you finalize graph? Are you allocating tensors of different sizes? Because of the way caching allocator works, you can run out of memory with static graph if sizes of memory allocations change.

Comment: No, I wasn't finalizing the graph, as I didn't know about this operation. The size of the tensors is the same during all iterations, (images of the same size, same batch size), so I guess this wasn't the problem. Does the finalize operation prevent from allocating different amounts of memory at each run operation?

Comment: finalizing graph prevents accidental modifications of the graph. The fact that reducing batch size 32 to 30 always solves the problem suggests it's not a real memory leak though

Comment: Maybe the computation of summaries, checkpointing, or other side information is leading to slightly higher GPU usage every few iterations?